# Inserting a variable as an sqlite column name using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Is it possible to insert a variable name into sqlite table as a column name? Questions is an array of objects. The goal is to grab the title property of each object and insert that as a column name.

```
db.serialize(() => {
  db.run("CREATE TABLE assessmentTable (test TEXT)");

  for(const q of questions){
    db.run("ALTER TABLE assessmentTable ADD VALUES(?)", q.title);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with that. Try replacing the quotes with back ticks so you can use the alter table statement as a template, then have it evaluate ${q.title} for column name. You may need to pass a definition for the table as well, not sure if that's required or not on sqlite3.

```
...
for(const q of questions){
 db.run(`ALTER TABLE assessmentTable ADD ${q.title}`);
}
...
```